# How to apply probability AND formula on this table below?Can easily be calculated just looking at table but struggling to apply the fornmual.

Tags: statistics

$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
         \hline
         & X = a & X = b & Total  \\
         \hline
         Y = c & 20 & 70 & 90 \\
         \hline
         Y = d & 15 & 45 & 60 \\
         \hline
         Total & 35 & 115 & 150 \\
         \hline
\end{array}$

$P(X = b, Y \ne c)$

$P(X = b) \rightarrow \frac{115}{150}$

$P(Y \ne c) \rightarrow  1 - P(Y \ne c) \rightarrow 1 - \frac{90}{150} \rightarrow \frac{60}{150}$

$P(X = b\hspace{.5em} \cap \hspace{.5em} Y \ne c) \rightarrow P(X = b) + P(Y \ne c) - P(X = b\hspace{.5 em} \cup\hspace{.5 em} Y \ne c) \rightarrow \frac{?}{?}$

im not sure how to calculate the prob since im getting 0 if i do this rn and off using the formula, using the table i can see its
$\frac{45}{150}$.

Comment: Question is not clear.

Comment: edited for clarificaiton

Comment: $\frac{115}{150} = P(X=b) = P(X=b, Y=c)+P(X=b, Y\ne c) = \cdots.$ Finish this appropriately, then subtract.

Comment: AHH THANK YOU I GET IT NOW